# cv2.VideoWriter is not working (windows 10)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I want to get the video and modify its frame rate. So I used `cv2.VideoCapture()` and `cv2.VideoWriter()`. But `cv2.videoWriter()` always writes an empty video file. **Why this output file is empty?**

Following is part of my code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, time

firstcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('D','I','V','X')
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','P','4','V')
#fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mpeg')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4',fourcc, 25,(int(firstcap.get(3)),int(firstcap.get(4))),True)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('output.mp4')


fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
print(fps)
```

Please can someone help me? I am working on windows 10.